# Is Mario Bosh/Bossi Triela's real father?

Tags: gunslinger-girl

Is Mario Bosh (or Bossi) Triela's real father?

In chapter 3, Triela captures, and later frees, a former mafia leader, Mario Bosh.

He claims to have come to the town to meet his daughter *(Triela?)*, whom he hasn't seen in several years.

He later sends Triela a bear as a Christmas present. (He claims to have sent his daughter a Christmas present every year, and Triela has received a bear for Christmas every year, supposedly from her handler.)

It seems odd that Triela also received exactly what she asked for for Christmas from Mario even though she never had the chance to tell him what she wanted.

Side note: this would actually make it the first year Triela has received a gift from her handler, not the first gift from Mario.

Also, Triela's handler hides around a corner, and doesn't show himself, allowing Triela to release Mario.

Is this an actual thing, or am I overthinking it?

Answer (score 5):

As the background story on [the wiki states](http://gunslingergirl.wikia.com/wiki/Triela) (I believe this part is handle further on in the manga so do consider this a spoiler)

> Originally from Tunisia, Triela was kidnapped and smuggled to Amsterdam by the Mafia, where she was drugged, tortured, and sexually assaulted during the routine taping of a snuff film. Victor Hartmann and Rachelle Belleut, acting on a lead from guilt-racked Camorra mafioso Mario Bossi, stormed the warehouse where she was being held captive and subsequently rescued her, just as she was succumbing to her injuries and to cardiac arrest.

Comment: I assume "Bosh" = "Bossi"?  That's a translation difference, right?

Comment: @Builder_K most likely a translation difference

Comment: I just can't tell from watching & reading if they are the same person or not.

Comment: @Builder_K The name Mario Bossi is the name used in the official released manga, there are some fan translations out there that use the name Bosh instead.  But in the end they are without a doubt the same person.